# Is there a way to access a JavaScript String variable in the CSS part of the HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to access a JavaScript String variable in the CSS part of the HTML?

For example, I've got a prefix that keeps occuring in all image URLs. It would only be proper to set a common variable with the prefix, for code maintenance. I'm looking for something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dropBoxPrefix = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/XXXX';
</script>

<style>
    html, body {
        background-image: url(dropBoxPrefix + '/bg.gif');
    }
    .re {
        background-image: url(dropBoxPrefix + '/header-bottom-left.png');
    }
    ul li {
        background-image: url(dropBoxPrefix + '/ok.png');
    }
    .networksTtl {
        background-image: url(dropBoxPrefix + '/Maps.png');
    }
</style>
```

Comment: No, but you could just put the last part of the URL as the background image URL and then use Javascript to fix it on page load.

Comment: You can use a server side language like PHP to construct dynamic styles. Or you can use LESS or SASS that's preprocessor of CSS

Comment: Or use something like LESS or SASS, which offer (via JS or PHP) variables within CSS.

Comment: I would highly recommend LESS or SASS over creating stylesheet using server side scripting. You would love these css pre-processors, and they would help you in many areas of css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you decide to go the LESS way, ( and could use the [simpLESS](http://wearekiss.com/simpless) compiler : example write code in filename background.less then drag and drop it into the simpleLess compiler and will get converted to background.css 
LESS Code:

```
   //variables
@dropBoxPrefix : 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/XXXX/';
@imageHTML : "bg.gif";
@imageRe : "header-bottom-left.png";
@imageULLI : "ok.png";
@imageNetworksTtl : "Maps.png";

//mixin
.backgroundImage(@image){
    @bi : "@{dropBoxPrefix}@{image}";
    background-image: url(@bi);
}

//styles
html, body{
    .backgroundImage(@imageHTML);
}
.re{
    .backgroundImage(@imageRe);
}
 ul li{
    .backgroundImage(@imageULLI);
}
.networksTtl{
    .backgroundImage(@imageNetworksTtl);
}
```

you will receive compiled CSS:

```
html,
body {
  background-image: url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/XXXX/bg.gif");
}
.re {
  background-image: url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/XXXX/header-bottom-left.png");
}
ul li {
  background-image: url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/XXXX/ok.png");
}
.networksTtl {
  background-image: url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/XXXX/Maps.png");
}
```

Comment: if this is the answer to your problem, this is not the answer to the question "Is there a way to access a JavaScript String variable in the CSS part of the HTML?"... maybe change the question then ?

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible in your way, but you can set this style property during js script execution

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/XXXX/bg.gif')";
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundimage.asp

Answer (score 1):

No way but a turnover could be to add styles in your head section with javascript, like this (jQuery example) :

```
var color1 = 'green';
$('<style>.yourclass { color:' + color1  +'}</style>').appendTo('head');
```

in pure js :

```
var color1 = 'green';
var css = '.yourclass { color:' + color1  +'}',
    head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';
if (style.styleSheet){
  style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
} else {
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
}
head.appendChild(style);
```